# Question on range

Tags: functions

> If the domain of the function $f(x)=|x|+[x]$ is $[-3,2)$ , then what is the image of $f(x)$? (where $[.]$ is greatest integer function).

**My attempt:**
In the question as they have mentioned domain so x lies in $[-3,2)$ but image means all the values in the domain satisfying by the function but I'm not able to do it please help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $0\le x-[x]\lt1$; what does that mean for $f(x)$ when $x\le0$?

Comment: It becomes -x as for the modulus

Comment: For modulus I can divide x as values  for <=0 or x>=0 but how to do it for [.]

Comment: You are correct that $|x|=-x$ for $x\le0$, so what is $f(x)$ in that range?  (see my initial comment)

Comment: Is it -3,-2,-1 for all x<0?

Comment: $f(x)=-x+[x]$, so what is the range of $f(x)$ when $x\le0$?

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you're telling me but I've divided it as:

Comment: -3<=x<-2, -2<=x<-1,-1<=x<0 for all x<0 and 1<=x<2,2<=x<3.

Comment: That approach should work (don't forget $0\le x\lt1$), though I was taking a short-cut by lumping together $-3\le x\le 0$

Comment: So 2<|x|<=3 and [x]=3 and clubbing together is the answer is it?thanks

Comment: When $x\le0$ then $f(x)=-x+[x]=-(x-[x])$, which is between $-1$ and $0$; what about when $0\le x\lt1$ or $1\le x\lt 2$?

Comment: The word "range" is somewhat ambiguous. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics). I suggest to use the word "image".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider how the function behaves an intervals $[n, n+1)$ (where $n$ is an integer.)

For $x \in [n,n+1)$, $[x]= n$ and so the "+[x]" part of the function acts as  constant.  So for $x \in [n,n+1)$ the function $f(x)$ acts as (and, for that particular interval, is equal to) $|x| + n$.

If $n \ge 0$ (and $x \in [n,n+1)$) then $|x| = x$ so this function acts simply as $f(x) = x + n$.  As $x$ may be as low as $n$ so $f(x)$ may be as low as $n+n=2n$, and $x$ has an upper limit (but never reaches) of $n+1$, $f(x)$ has an upper limit of $(n+1)+n = 2n+1)$, it follows that the range on that interval is $[2n, 2n+1)$.

If $n < 0$  (and $x \in [n,n+1)$ then $|x| = -x$ so this function (for this interval and this interval only) is $f(x) = -x + n$ and $x$ may be as low as $n$ so $f(x)$ may be as high as $-n + n = 0$, and $x$ has an upper limit of $n+1$ so $f(x)$ has a lower limit of $-(n+1) +n = -1$.  So for that interval the range of $f(x)$ is $(-1,0]$.  (Note: the function is not injective.  For negative values the function repeats itself.)

So on the intervals $[-3,-2)$, $[-2,-1)$ and $[-1,0)$ the range is $(-1,0]$

On the intervals $[0,1)$ and $[1,2)$ the ranges are $[0,1)$ and $[2,3)$ respectively.

Putting it together the range of the function is $(-1,0] \cup (-1,0] \cup(-1,0] \cup[0,1) \cup [2,3) = (-1,1) \cup [2,3)$.

Comment: Argh! So many typoes!

Comment: like "may may".

Comment: My typos were writing $(-1,0]$ as $[-1,0)$ and $[0,1)$ as $(0,1]$ even for one edition $[0,1)$ as $(-1,0]$.  "may may" is the least of my worries.

Answer (score 1):

When $x\le0$, $f(x)=-x+[x]$.  Since $0\le x-[x]<1,$ this means $-1<f(x)\le0$ when $x\le0$.

When $0\le x\lt 1, f(x)=x$, so $0\le f(x)\lt 1$.

When $1\le x\lt 2, f(x)=x+1$, so $2\le f(x)\lt 3$.

In summary, the range of $f(x)$ when $x\in [-3,2)$ is

> $(-1,1)\cup[2,3)$.

Comment: Why should we include 2<=x<3 when domain of x is [-3,2)?

Comment: We shouldn't; I didn't

Comment: Is it because for any value of x between 1 and 2 we get f(x) in the range 2 and 3?

Comment: @Kanchi Yes, since $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ for $1 \leq x < 2 \implies x + \lfloor x \rfloor = x + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Given function $$f(x) = |x| + [x]$$
[image]
Case 1: If $x <0$, then $x = - |x| $ $$\Rightarrow f(x) = |x| + [-|x|] = |x| - [|x|] - 1= \{|x|\} - 1 $$
Where $\{\cdot \}$ is fractional integer function whose range is $[0,1)$, so when for this case range of $f(x)$ is $(-1,0)$
Case 2: If $x \ge 0 $, Here we have  to analyse piecewisely,

For $x \in [0,1)$ ,$[x] = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = |x| \Rightarrow f(x) \in [0,1)$
For $x \in [1,2) , [x] = 1, \Rightarrow f(x) = |x| + 1 ,\Rightarrow f(x) \in [2,3)$

Hence, Range of function is $ (-1,0) \cup [0,1)\cup [2,3)$

Comment: or simply $[-1,1)\cup[2,3)$

Comment: but I think it's really $\color{red}(-1,1)\cup[2,3)$, as I answered

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Comment: Desmos > Mathematica